# Solving optimization problem by penalty method

Tags: optimization

Given this minimization problem:

$$
\text{minimize }\, \,  x_1^2 + 2x_2^2 \\
\text{subject to } \, \, x_1 + x_2 = 3
$$

I wish to solve this using the penalty method, what I've done so far:

$$
\text{minimize} \, \, f(x) \\
\text{where}  \, \, f(x) = x_1^2 + 2x_2^2 + \gamma(x_1 +x_2 -3)^2
$$

I try to find $x_1, x_2$ using First Order Necessary Condition:

$$
2(1 + \gamma)x_1 + 2\gamma x_2 - 6\gamma = 0 \\
2\gamma x_1 + 2(2+ \gamma)x_2 - 6\gamma = 0 \\
$$

What I do next is to use row reduction to solve this problem:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
2(1+\gamma) & 2\gamma & | \, \, 6 \gamma \\
2\gamma & 2(2+\gamma)& | \, \, 6 \gamma
\end{bmatrix} \\
\downarrow \\
\begin{bmatrix}
1+\gamma & \gamma & | \, \, 3 \gamma \\
\gamma & 2+\gamma& | \, \, 3 \gamma
\end{bmatrix} \\
$$

Dividing by $\gamma$ and letting $\gamma \rightarrow \infty$:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & | \, \, 3 \\
1 & 1 & | \, \, 3
\end{bmatrix} \\
$$

Which does not give me an unique solution, according to the textbook the unique solution is to be

$$
x^* = \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}
$$

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you very much

Comment: The textbook tells us to use that penalty function, probably because of Courant Beltrami penalty function. I let $\gamma \to \infty$ because that is when the penalty method converges.

Comment: The mistake is letting $\gamma \to \infty$ *before* completing the Gaussian elimination.

Comment: @user1337 That is correct! Thank you very much.

Comment: But why don't you use completing square method for this particular problem?

Comment: @Martund How would one proceed then?

Comment: @BobPen, Added an answer for that. Check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mistake was to let $\gamma \to \infty$ before completing the elimination, thanks  for pointing this out @user1337.

Correction:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1+\gamma & \gamma & | \, \, 3 \gamma \\
\gamma & 2+\gamma& | \, \, 3 \gamma
\end{bmatrix} \\
\downarrow\\
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & | \, \, \frac{6 \gamma}{2+3\gamma} \\
0 & 1 & | \, \, \frac{3 \gamma} {2+3\gamma}
\end{bmatrix} \\
$$

Now letting $\gamma \to \infty$ and using L'Hopital:

$$
x^* = \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative solution using completing squares method (since OP asked in comments):

We wish to minimize
\begin{align}
(3-x_2)^2+2x_2^2&=3x_2^2-6x_2+9\\
&=3((x_2-1)^2+2)
\end{align}
which is clearly minimum when $x_2=1$ and therefore $x_1=2$.